# Rewrite: ( I last )

Tags: grammaticality

Rewrite the following sentence using the word in brackets to give the same meaning :

> The last time I saw you was at your party.   ( I last )

Comment: Your sentence already uses those words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing "part" is a misspelling of "party", here. Either way, you can rephrase it like this:

> I last saw you at your party.